# Jaybird SocketInputStream.socketread0 thread blocking

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, jaybird, firebird-3.0

I am using JDBC connection to firebird.

```
<groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
```

When I am reading data with:

```
resultSet.next(); //resultSet is instance of FBResultSet
```

sometimes thread will block here:

```
 private native int socketRead0(FileDescriptor fd,
                                   byte b[], int off, int len,
                                   int timeout)
        throws IOException;
```

And the thread will never continue. I need to restart whole app. :(

How can I fix this issue? I have tried some parameters from here:
https://dzone.com/articles/threads-stuck-in-javanetsocketinputstreamsocketrea

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=10000
```

But without positive result. I dont even know, what the timeout value is. I cant debug it in that place. (java.net.SocketInputStream)

The connection to the database is connected to the cloud server, and I think that is the problem.

Is it possible to somehow fix this issue? Or setup the timeout to firebird jdbc?

Thanks for any answer.

**Edit:** 
here is the screen of jammed thread:
[image]

Comment: You need to look at the JDBC configuration to solve this.

Comment: Are you using a custom value for `TcpRemoteBufferSize` in `firebird.conf`? Could you also post a thread-dump of the stuck thread? What transaction isolation level are you using? As a workaround, you can configure the connection property `soTimeout` to set the socket read timeout (see also the [Jaybird manual](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connectionproperties-other)), but hangs like this are either an indication of Firebird being blocked on a read, or a problem in the wire protocol. Having a [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: soTimeout helped. Thanks you very much. :)

Comment: I am not using the TcpRemoteBufferSize, should I?

Comment: @Altair No, when testing Jaybird, I have observed problems with hanging reads with Firebird 3 and 4 if wire crypt is used (the default) and the TcpRemoteBufferSize in firebird.conf is set to values that are not multiples of 4 (or maybe 8). However, it would be good to know if this is a bug in Firebird or Jaybird, or if this is just a matter of Firebird being blocked waiting for a lock, so a [mre] and a stacktrace of the hang would be helpful. You could also send it to the firebird-java mailinglist or post it on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC

Comment: I will try to make minimal reproducible example. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause in your case is a bug in Jaybird 3.0.4 to 3.0.7 (and 4.0.0-beta-1) with Firebird 3 (and 4) when wire encryption is enabled in firebird.conf (setting `WireCrypt = Enabled`).

I had previously only seen this problem with Jaybird 4 when the tests of Jaybird were run in a specific order, and as that version is not yet released, I hadn't given it priority to find the root cause.

With your help (thanks again!) I was able to identify the problem. This bug is now fixed in Jaybird 3.0.8, which is available from [Firebird: JDBC Driver](https://firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/#jaybird3).

### Explanation of the bug

Certain types of buffers (eg column data) in the Firebird wire protocol are padded with bytes to multiples of four. The implementation in Jaybird relied on `InputStream.skip(long)` to skip this padding.

Specifically, it did:

```
public int skipFully(int n) throws IOException {
    int total = 0;
    int cur;
    while (total < n && (cur = (int) in.skip(n - total)) > 0) {
        total += cur;
    }
    return total;
}
```

This worked fine without wire encryption, because the combination of the `skip` implementations in `BufferedInputStream` and `SocketInputStream` would at least skip 1 byte for each call to `skip` unless the socket was closed.

When `CipherInputStream` was added, this expectation no longer held: if the `BufferedInputStream` has no bytes in its buffer, it will call `skip(long)` on the `CipherInputStream`, and if that is at the end of its buffer, it will skip 0 bytes (which is allowed for `skip`).

As a result, Jaybird could skip 1, 2 or 3 bytes too few, which caused subsequent reads to read wrong data. Eventually this would either cause a buffer size to be read incorrectly, causing the read to block waiting for more data, or it would result in Jaybird reading a wrong operation code, which will cause an exception with a message starting with *"Unsupported or unexpected operation code"*.

### Workarounds or solutions for other problems with similar behaviour

As a workaround to hanging connections, you can use the connection property `soTimeout` to set the socket read timeout (see [Jaybird Manual, appendix A.2 Other properties](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connectionproperties-other)).

The problem could also be that Firebird is 'just' waiting indefinitely on a lock. To rule out Firebird waiting on a lock, you could also change the transaction wait mode or timeout. The default for Jaybird is to use an indefinite wait.

For example, to change the wait mode of read committed to no-wait, you can set connection property `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` with value `read_committed,rec_version,write,nowait`.

To use wait, but with a timeout, you can use value `read_committed,rec_version,write,wait,lock_timeout=5`. This will apply a 5 second lock timeout.

If your problem is due to Firebird waiting on a lock held by another transaction, then this should result in an exception with the text containing *lock conflict on no wait transaction* (for the `nowait` option) or *lock time-out on wait transaction* (for the `lock_timeout` option).

See also [Jaybird Manual, appendix A.3 Transaction isolation levels](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connectionproperties-isolation-levels) and [Jaybird Manual, section 6.4. Transaction Isolation Levels](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#transactions-isolation-levels) (although I now see that I will need to add more information in there).